# parse error in civicrm_handler_relationship_relationship.inc since upgrade to 4.6.11

Tags: drupal-views

Since upgrade the site is broken with the following message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home/ablaze/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_relationship_relationship.inc on line 58

Line 58 looks as though it is properly closed and removing the semi-colon just introduces another error.

As an emergency repair I've dropped in the file from the last version and it is working again.

Differences in files:

Line 25

old:

```
$options = array(0 => 'Any');
```

new:

```
$options = array();
```

Line 53

new line inserted:

```
 '#multiple' => TRUE,
```

Murphey's law being what it is I've broken my develoipment environment so can't work out anything else for a while.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I do have some questions that might or might not point us in the right direction: Do you get this error for every view, or are some working? If some work, what are the differences between the ones that work and the ones that don't? What versions of civi did you upgrade from and to? And lastly, which version of views are you using?

Comment: Thanks naomisi - having any views that call this code breaks the whole site. I am in the process of setting up my development environment again, though only in between other tasks - I'll experiment with disabling certain views - I suspect it is the ones that use Views relationships on civicrm relationships - views version 7x.3.13 - upgraded from 4.6.10

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this error, too. It's in 4.6.11 and 4.6.12. It appears to be fixed in 4.7.1.

Line 56 in the file is the culprit. It should be

```
'#description' => t('Choose to limit this relationship to one or more specific types of CiviCRM relationship.'),
```

Here's the [commit that fixes it](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/commit/c096bf25445faa52cd93a9158cd4f9c585f499c1#diff-8e076be511b403be2e8cc3b32fa13229).

Comment: Thank you SO much for posting this. This error was driving me nuts.